# Initializing pointers during declaration in c

Tags: c

How does the following work?

```
char *str="string";
printf("str is %s\n",str);
```

but the below one gives segmentation fault

```
int *i=3;
printf("int is %d\n",*i);
```

Comment: You just tried to access memory location with address of `3` which doesn't belong to you. Segment fault. The `*str = "string"` internally creates a string in memory that belongs to you, and its address is put in `str`. That works.

Comment: you want `int *i=(int[]){3};`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string literal such as `"string"` is a `char[7]` stored in a read-only memory location. Array names can decay to pointers to their first element, so it is possible to initialize a `char*` to such a literal expression.

An integer literal such as `3` is just an int rvalue which is not stored anywhere. The initialization `int* i = 3` initializes `i` to point to a memory location with value `3`. This is unlikely to be a valid location, which is why de-referencing `i` gives you a segmentation violation.

Comment: It is not `const` in C, unfortunately, but only in read-only memory.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks. For some reason I thought that had changed in C11. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In case of string literals, compiler allocate space for it in memory. `str` will be initializes with the starting address of the allocated chunk.
In case of `int *i=3;`, compiler initializes `i` with the address value `3`. Generally lower addresses are reserved for operating systems and programs will most likely crash on accessing these location